# How to create read-only user in the Docker Registry v2?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-registry, dockerhub

**I'd like to have 2 users in Docker Registry v2:**

- user1 - read-write (pull-push)
- user2 - read-only (pull only)

How to create read-only user ?

Comment: Could you solve your requirement?

Comment: Hey @JRichardsz, Amazon ECR, and additionally I recommend to check Harbor